# YII: Value of variables not saving in the database

Tags: php, database, yii

I am new to YII. I know this question has been asked a lot of times before nut i can really find an answer. So, please take a look. 
I am saving some data in the database from my PaypalController.php

Here is the code of PaypalController.

```
$transid = $paymentResult['TRANSACTIONID'];
$profileid = $recurringResult['PROFILEID'];

/*var_dump($transid);
var_dump($profileid);
exit;*/

$payment = new Payment;
$payment->user_id = 2;
$payment->feature = 'import sending servers';
$payment->transaction_id = $transid;
$payment->amount = 10;
$payment->profile_id = $profileid;
if($payment->save()){
    //var_dump($recurringResult);exit;
    //echo "<script>alert('Your payment is succesful');</script>";
    $this->redirect('../email-hustler/index');
}else{
    print_r($payment->getErrors());
    exit;
}
```

And here is the code of my Payment model

```
public $user_id;
    public $feature;
    public $transaction_id;
    public $amount;
    public $profile_id;
    public $is_active;

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{payment}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = array(
            array('user_id, feature, transaction_id, amount, profile_id, is_active', 'safe'),
        );

        return CMap::mergeArray($rules, parent::rules());
    }

   public function attributeLabels(){
       return array(
           'user_id' => 'user_id',
           'feature' => 'feature',
           'transaction_id' => 'transaction_id',
           'amount' => 'amount',
           'profile_id' => 'profile_id',
           'is_active' => 'is_active',
       );
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
```

Now the problem is the value of the variables is not saving but the value i am passing static are saved.

var_dump of variables is giving me correct output.

Please help.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which variable is now stored in database?

Comment: Problem is solved. It was caused due to the cache set in yii itself. Cache was set for longer period thats why database schema was not updating and hence causing the problems. Thank you though.